# python2.7 and tox and virtualenv integration when debugging in pycharm (community)

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, integration, tox

I am running tox successfully via CLI to run several .py's but within pycharm I get the following error when running against tox.ini which is in my project library. I suspect environment variables are not setup correctly for jb_tox_runner to import certain modules. I.e. the .py cannot find them.

```
Testing started at 4:39 PM ...
/usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/pycharm-community-2018.2/helpers/pycharm/_jb_tox_runner.py -e py27 -- -v --fulltrace tests/cap_plan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.2/helpers/pycharm/_jb_tox_runner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tox import config as tox_config, session as tox_session
ImportError: No module named tox

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here are my run/debug config and python interpreter/virtualenv:

[image: rundebugconfig]
[image: interpretervirtualenvsettings]

Answer (score 0):

After research i answered the question myself. I need to install tox intepreter and then the tox module was available to pycharm even though i had installed tox and virtualenv from cli outside of pycharm

Comment: What do you mean "install tox interpreter"? Can you elaborate on where to install?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm requires Tox to be available within the project's virtual environment.  To install Tox, so it is available, choose:

**Preferences -> Project: [PROJECT_NAME] -> Project Interpreter**

Choose the relevant interpreter in the right-hand pane, or create a new one.  The controls for adding packages to the virtual environment are near the bottom (see screenshot). Click on the "**+**"symbol and a new screen will appear where you can install **tox**.